# how to get value outside foreach controller codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

I want to get value from `$data2['menu_down']` to send for my view, but I always get last value form `$data2`

```
public function index(){
    $data['menu'] = $this->M_home->tampil_menu_utama();
    foreach ($data['menu'] as $menus) {
        $idmenu = $menus->menuid;

        $data2['menu_down'] = $this->M_home->tampil_menu_down($idmenu);

    }
    $this->load->view('head',array_merge($data,$data2));
    $this->load->view('home');
    $this->load->view('foot');
}
```

Comment: not sure I understood your question correctly but seems that you need to add `[]` to `$data2['menu_down']`. i.e. `$data2['menu_down'][] = $this->M_home->tampil_menu_down($idmenu);`

Answer (score -1):

You need to take `$data2` as array;

```
public function index(){
    $data['menu'] = $this->M_home->tampil_menu_utama();
    $data2 = array(); //initialize your variable with array; 
    foreach ($data['menu'] as $menus) {
        $idmenu = $menus->menuid;

        $data2['menu_down'][] = $this->M_home->tampil_menu_down($idmenu);

    }
    $result['menu_down']=array_merge($data,$data2);
    $this->load->view('head',$result);
    $this->load->view('home');
    $this->load->view('foot');
}
```

Comment: oke thank Mayank, but my view error "Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: @FransChaniago I have update my answer please check it

Comment: oke but same now i get error "Message: Undefined variable: menu" in my view with  foreach($menu as $menus)

Comment: Please try like `foreach($menu_down as $menus)`

Comment: please check with `print_r($menu_down)` in view which data are transfer from controller to view